# Custom Domain Name on Azure site working, but always redirects to azurewebsites.net?

Tags: azure

I set up a custom domain on a SHARED mode Azure site, with a CNAME for www.lakestarlodge.com, and an A record for lakestarlodge.com.  Both work - I can type either into my browser and get to the site.

However, I just noticed that when the site finished loading that it had been redirected to lakestarlodge.azurewebsites.net.  I can't be sure, but I could have sworn it wasn't doing that before tonight.  Is there a setting somewhere I need to change, or is this normal behavior for a custom domain on an Azure site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I knew that couldn't be the default behavior!  Turns out, I had set up GoDaddy with DNS & "Domain Forwarding," and the Domain Forwarding (which was not left on intentionally) kept overriding the A record.  So DNS was effectively being skipped.  Got it all resolved!

Answer (score 0):

For all the people that might still have the same problem, in my case I was using wordpress and when I created the site I choosed the Wordpress default address: mysite.azurewebsites.com.  So it wasn´t a Wordpress Issue.
You cand find how to solve this on this previus [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742852/configuring-azure-website-to-always-resolve-to-custom-domain?noredirect=1&lq=1).